# Getting Host requires authentication while sending WMS GetMAP API request in QGIS

Tags: geoserver, qgis, wms

I am very new to `QGIS` tool.While sending `WMS` `GetMAP` API request using `QGIS` tool I am getting

#Error

> Host requires authentication

However when run that url in browser I am getting the expected MAP.

[image]

How can I get rid of such error.Kindly advice.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to turn of whatever security rules you have set on the WMS. Or you can fill in and store the user name and password that the service requires in QGIS.